# Meteor - Query Embedded Documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I would like to fetch only specific fields in embedded documents of my collection.

One Document of my Collection:

```
"_id" : "fDa9J245hkKnZyipM",
"OrderID" : "qPypJCWov79dQ2nc2",
    "MWLink" : {
            "LinkType" : "KRF - PPUI - LOO",
            "LinkID" : "test3",
            "SiteA" : "placeA",
            "SiteB" : "placeB"
    }
```

My helper:

```
        linkID: function() {
            return MyCollection.find({},{"MWLink.LinkID": 1}).fetch();
        }
```

I would like to have this result:

```
{"_id": "fDa9J245hkKnZyipM", "MWLink": {"LinkID": "test3"}},
{"_id": "kioa56245hrTnzuiL", "MWLink": {"LinkID": "test5"}},
....
```

But I get the whole documents...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fields` ([?](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find)):

```
return MyCollection.find({},{fields:{"MWLink.LinkID": 1}}).fetch();
```

If you feel you need a bit more power on what comes up you can use `map` ([?](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/map)) or a `transform` ([?](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find)):

```
var transform = function(doc) {
    return {
        MWLink : {
            LinkID: doc.MWLink.LinkID
        }
    }
}


//A transform returns a cursor
return MyCollection.find({}, {transform: transform});

//Map returns an array of documents
return MyCollection.find({}).map(transform);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I was looking for! I should stop reading the mongodb manuals and should start reading the meteor docs...